# What are the two values inside angle brackets < > in a device tree .dts file?

Tags: embedded, devices, device-tree

Following is the [code snippet](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-xilinx/plain/conf/machine/boards/zedboard/zedboard-zynq7-board.dtsi) in a device tree file:

```
flash@0 {
                compatible = "n25q128";
                reg = <0x0>;
                spi-max-frequency = <50000000>;
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <1>;
                partition@qspi-fsbl-uboot {
                    label = "qspi-fsbl-uboot";
                    reg = <0x0 0x100000>;
                };
                partition@qspi-linux {
                    label = "qspi-linux";
                    reg = <0x100000 0x500000>;
                };
                partition@qspi-device-tree {
                    label = "qspi-device-tree";
                    reg = <0x600000 0x20000>;
                };
                partition@qspi-rootfs {
                    label = "qspi-rootfs";
                    reg = <0x620000 0x5E0000>;
                };
                partition@qspi-bitstream {
                    label = "qspi-bitstream";
                    reg = <0xC00000 0x400000>;
                };
            };
```

My simple question is what are the two values in < >? for example in reg = <0x600000 0x20000>;

I thought it is initial and final address , but this will be meaning less here since final cannot be lower than initial.

Comment: Given the values, I'd bet for `<offset length>`.

Answer (score 2):

Angle brackets (<>) denotes a "32-bit unsigned integer array" and I believe they are often refereed to as "cells". 
In the case with the `reg` property, the first value is the (offset) address and the second the length of the register(s). Note that it is also possible to have multiple ranges i.e.

```
reg = <addr1 addr1_length addr2 addr2_length  ... addrN addrN_length>
```

Sources:

- http://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage#How_Addressing_Works
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md

Answer (score 1):

**It does not have to be just two numbers in general**

Furthermore, as explained at: https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage#How_Addressing_Works it does not have to be just two numbers each.

E.g., in 64 bit devices, we often have:

```
#address-cells = <2>;
#size-cells = <2>;
```

which implies address and offset are of type:

```
reg = <0x1 0x2 0x3 0x4>
```

which represents a region with:

- base address: 00000001 00000002 (composed of 2 32-bit numbers due to `#address-cells = <2>;`)
- length: 00000003 00000004 (composed of 2 32-bit numbers due to `#size-cells = <2>;`)

This is because each number in the device tree is 32-bit wide by definition, so we need two for each 64 bit value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `reg<0xxxx 0xxxx>` stands for `reg<offset length>`.

`offset` is the base address of the device and length will determine the range of address of the given device.